# Signing a mixed mode C++ assembly

Tags: .net, security, c++-cli

Can you sign a C++ CLI application that is partially managed and partially unmanaged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can sign a mixed mode .Net assembly.  It will still require full trust to run though.